# Match RH[A-ZA-Z] with grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression

How can I match with `grep` the regex RH[A-ZA-Z],
 so string includes RH with two characters that both are a letter between A and Z?

I tried this but without success:

```
 yum list-security --security | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | grep RH[A-ZA-Z]
 Loaded
 RHEA-2014:1307
 RHSA-2014:1326
 RHBA-2014:1388
 RH@A-2014:1389
 RHSA-2014:1392
 RHSA-2014:1389
 RH7A-2014:1392
 RHSAA-2014:1389
 RHMAW-2014:1392
```

This is what I expected:

```
 RHEA-2014:1307
 RHSA-2014:1326
 RHBA-2014:1388
 RHSA-2014:1392
 RHSA-2014:1389
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`RH[A-ZA-Z]` is a regular expression that includes a single character class that repeats the same set of characters twice.  It matches `RH` followed by any character from `A` to `Z`. It places no restrictions on the fourth character, it doesn't even require there to be a fourth character.

Obviously, that doesn't do what you want.

Try this: `RH[A-Z][A-Z]` or (with extended `grep -E` or perl `grep -P` regexps) `RH[A-Z]{2}`

Also, it's a good idea to put single-quotes (or double-quotes if you need to include a variable or command substitution) around regular expressions to make sure the shell won't try to expand them as globs - e.g. if you had a filename `RHAA` in the current directory, the shell would expand your argument to RHAA and that's **all** that your `grep` would see:

```
$ grep RH[A-Z][A-Z] yael.txt  | wc -l
7
$ touch RHAA
$ grep RH[A-Z][A-Z] yael.txt  | wc -l
0
```

equivalent to:

```
$ grep RHAA yael.txt  | wc -l
0
```

but it gets worse.  If you also have a file called 'RHAB', the `grep` command line will expand to:

```
grep RHAA RHAB yael.txt
```

so `grep` will search for regexp `RHAA` in file `RHAB` as well as stdin and/or the named file(s) you want to search.

**Use grep with quotes instead: `grep 'RH[A-Z][A-Z]'`**

---

Update:

If you want `RH` followed by only two `[A-Z]` characters (but no more than two), use this instead:

```
grep 'RH[A-Z][A-Z][^A-Z]' yael.txt
```

The third character class `[^A-Z]` begins with `^`, which negates or inverts the class.  In other words it matches any character **except** `A` to `Z`.

---

And you probably want to anchor the match to the beginning of the line, regardless of which version of the regexp you use.  You use `^` for that too, but it has a completely different meaning outside of `[]`.  It's the beginning-of-line anchor.  For example, this:

```
grep '^RH[A-Z][A-Z][^A-Z]' yael.txt
```

will only match lines **beginning** with `RH[A-Z][A-Z][^A-Z]`, and will **not** match lines with that pattern anywhere else.

Comment: Your expression also matches the 3-letter suffixes, which the OP doesn't seem to want - don't you need to anchor the back end with a hyphen `RH[A-Z][A-Z]-` or non-[A-Z] character `RH[A-Z][A-Z][^A-Z]`?

Comment: @steeldriver - true...i thought about adding it but it's not what the OP asked for "string include RH with two charterers that both can be between A-Z".   i'll update my answer anyway.

Comment: Won't it be better to use `grep "RH[[:upper:]][[:upper:]][^[:alpha:]]"`?

Comment: for some kinds of input text, possibly.  but it seems a bit unlikely that RedHat Security Advisories will have non-ascii characters in the id.

Comment: What? Why not `RH[A-Z]{0,2}` or whatever?

Comment: he wants exactly two (or maybe 2+), not 0-2.